# Can a unicode character be used for the zsh prompt instead of the '%' symbol?

Tags: zsh, prompt, unicode

Macbooks now default to `zsh` for new users. Existing users have the option of switching to it. I've made the switch and would like to make my prompt look the way it did in `bash`. I have this for the most part, but one thing I did in `bash` was set my user prompt character to an apple instead of the default dollar symbol. This was done using unicode.

Is there a way to accomplish this in `zsh` as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course. Like in bash, you can set the `PS1` variable to your choice of prompt. In bash, you set it in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`); in zsh, you set it in `.zshrc`. Zsh has a completely different set of prompt escapes (`\thing` in bash, `%differentthing` in zsh). See the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Simple-Prompt-Escapes) for a list.

For example put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
PS1='%B%2~ %b '
```

Or, to have a green apple normally but a red apple if the previous command failed:

```
PS1='%B%2~ %(?:%F{green}%f:%F{red}%f)%b '
```

You may be interested in my [summary of differences between bash and zsh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh/361957#361957).

Comment: Ah...so it's a literal string instead of unicode? Is it still possible to do that while still getting the `#` prompt as root?

Comment: What do you mean by “literal string instead of unicode”? A string is made of unicode characters. To get a different prompt for root, use a `%()` construct like in my red/green example, but with `!` as the condition: `%(!:#:)`

Comment: I guess I don't get it. When I see your response I only see the green and red apples. I don't see you inserting actual unicode into the prompt string. I was asking about using the unicode "code" as in `U+...` to indicate a character.

Comment: @theillien The prompt could use explicit characters, any of the Unicode. There is no need to use `\U01f34e`, even if you could. It is the same in bash.

Comment: @theillien If you want to use a Unicode character by number, it works the same as in bash: `$'\U0001f34e'`